# Object class as array

Tags: vb.net, object

like every class in .net does Arrays also inherit Object

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do.

Arrays are instances of generic types that inherit the abstract `Array` class.

[MSDN discusses this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z4khca9.aspx)

Comment: Even though the article discusses C# I believe you are still correct